# Электронные таблицы Excell на php

Tags: jquery-ui, php, javascript

Добрый день, подскажите,где найти информацию по созданию электронных таблиц типа экселя?
Хочу,что б на моём сервере была возможность работать с таблицами, как у гугла и майкрософт.
Есть ли компонент jquery или что-то подобное для встраивания таблицы?
Спасибо

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 3):

Смотря что вы ожидаете получить от таблиц, полноценный эксель конечно возможно, но я пока не встречал, вот посмотрите ссылки, надеюсь вам будет это полезно

[Раз](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-amazing-jquery-tables/)

[Два. Это мне больше всего по душе](http://www.jtable.org/)

[Три](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/)